# Правильное построение условий php

Tags: php

Как правильно построить большие условия проверки?

Например код:

```php
if ($test['status'] == 1) {
  if ($test['id'] == 2) {
    if ($test['user'] == 4) {
      if ($test['auth'] == true) {
        if ($test['map'] == 'russia') {
          if ($test['name'] == 'john') {
            $result = 1;
          } else {
            $result = 2;
          }
        } else {
          $result = 2;
        }
      } else {
        $result = 2;
      }
    } else {
      $result = 2;
    }
  } else {
    $result = 2;
  }
} else {
  $result = 0;
}
```

Выглядит не очень, читается плохо и если условий больше то код превращается в ёлку.

Как правильно формировать массивные условия проверки и для каждого присваивать некий результат, то есть избегать OR условий?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$check = [ 
         'status' => ['v' => 1,  'false' => 0],
         'id'     => ['v' => 2,  'false' => 2],             
         'user'   => ['v' => 4,  'false' => 2],
         'auth'   => ['v' => true,  'false' => 2],
         'map'    => ['v' => 'russia',  'false' => 2],
         'name'   => ['v' => 'john',    'false' => 2, 'true' => 1],
    ];

$doCheck = function($test) use ($check){
               foreach($check as $field => $opts){
                   if( $test[$field] !== $opts['v']) return $opts['false'];
               }
               return $opts['true'];
            };
```

можно еще вместо строковых ключей 'true/false' использовать сами занчения true/false или индексы 0\1, и в итоге массив будет вида `'name' => [2, 1, 'v' => 'jonh']` но это будет менее понятно и наглядно.

Answer (score 7):

https://ideone.com/S2wqPb

```
<?php

function test($obj) {
  $checks = [
    ['status',   1,          0],
    ['id',       2,          2],
    ['user',     4,          3],
    ['auth',     true,       4],
    ['map',      'russia',   5],
    ['name',     'john',     6],
  ];

  foreach ($checks as $check) {
    if ($obj[$check[0]] != $check[1]) {
      return $check[2];
    }
  }

  return 1;
}

echo test([status => 1, id => 2, user => 7]);
```

Стоило бы сделать массив объектов или словарей вместо двумерного массива, но мне лень.

Comment: аххах, чето я долго свой код форматировал тут :D

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант

```php
if ($test['status'] == 1) {
  if (
    $test['id'] == 2 &&
    $test['user'] == 4 &&
    $test['auth'] &&
    $test['map'] === 'russia' &&
    $test['name'] === 'john'
  ) {
    $result = 1;
  } else {
    $result = 2;
  }
} else {
  $result = 0;
}
```

Второй вариант

```php
function getRes($test) {
  if ($test['status'] != 1) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (
    $test['id'] == 2 &&
    $test['user'] == 4 &&
    $test['auth'] &&
    $test['map'] === 'russia' &&
    $test['name'] === 'john'
  ) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 2
}

$result = getRes($test);
```

Comment: мне показалось, что там все же разные резалты во всех ветках должны быть

Comment: да. Эта конструкция читаема, когда результаты при большинстве условий одинаковые, а если разные - то ничего не изменит.

Comment: @teran в исходном коде одинаковые

Comment: @AntonBogomolov Что еще я должен был угадать? Посмотрите на второй вариант